# Injecting a javascript file with the fewest possible characters?

Tags: javascript, code-golf, bookmarklet, minimize

I'm working on a bookmarklet, and thought I'd throw down a challenge: how to inject an external javascript file from a link in as few characters as possible.

Here's the shortest I was able to come up with:

```
javascript:(function(d){d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('script')).src='URL'})(document)
```

That's 88 characters without the URL.

Can the Stack Overflow javascript gurus here do better? I'll be accepting the working answer with the fewest characters, so put on your thinking caps!

(One thing: the bookmarklet must work in all major browsers. [This](http://pastie.org/309899) is a clever solution, but doesn't work in all major browsers, because it returns a value.)

Comment: When you say ALL browsers do you mean the big 3 (Firefox, IE, Safari) or do you mean ALL browsers.

Comment: How about all of those supported by the latest jQuery? From their site: IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+, Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that String.prototype isn't contaminated, we can save some chars.

```
javascript:with(document)(body.appendChild(createElement('script')).src='URL')._
```

Comment: I like how you used the word "contaminated" haha

Answer (score 6):

```
javascript:void(with(document)body.appendChild(createElement('script')).src='URL')
```

79 characters. Credit to [Ben Blank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46387/ben-blank) for the use of `void`.

Comment: but you're using with, which is frowned on in some circles.

Comment: Well, being that the only scope of this code is a bookmarklet, I don't think the usual reasons to avoid it apply.

Comment: Most things are frowned on in some circles. For example, some people frown upon IF, saying that GOTOs were much simpler. They are, of course, completely wrong. :-)

Comment: Never use with, unless your scope is pretty simple. In this case, it's OK.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you're wrapping this in a function enclosure — it seems to work perfectly well without and is almost a dozen characters shorter:

```
javascript:void(document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='URL')
```

Aside from that, however, your implementation looks pretty minimalist.

Comment: This is why: http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/rules.asp#ReturnValues

This approach will return the URL, so it won't work in some browsers.

Comment: I see, fixed. Still shorter, though not by as much. :-)